# What is the meaning of pi selectivity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, optical-properties, stereoselectivity

I came across this term while going through a research paper for the first time of organic chemistry on diastereoselectivity of tricyclo[2.1.0.02,5]pentan-3-ones. I am not familiar with the term and on doing a google search I came across papers on pi facial selectivity.

This is my first time reading a research paper which is of certainly a different standard all together, so any kind of help in letting me know about the general definition of the term and how it is related to diastereoselectivity will be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What paper is this? Context will help.

Comment: Is the paper this one? https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288797274_1-Substituted-tricyclo210025pentan-3-ones_Revisiting_the_diastereoselectivity

Comment: Pie Selectivity - Which pie do you like best? (a) apple, (b) blueberry or (c) cherry. .

Comment: Beside addition of the reference will help the discussion; assuming it is about the reaction on the carbonyl group with a nucleophile (e.g., a Grignard), check if it is not a typo.  A plausible alternative were _re_ / _si_ selectivity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prochirality).

Comment: @Safdar yes that is the paper, I was working on.